# How to check whether a vector is subset of another one in R?

Tags: r, subset

Say, I have two vectors:

```
A <- c(1,0,0,1,0,0,0)
```

and

```
B <- c(1,0,0,1,0,1,1)
```

By my definition, A is subset of B, (both vectors contain binary values only) if and only if

- `A` and `B` have the same length and thus have the same number of elements;
- `A` should have either `0` or `1` at all places wherever `B` has `1`
- `A` can have only `0`s at all places where `B` has `0`s.

Now I wish to write a code that would verify something within the lines of

```
if(A subset of B){}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `A` subset of `B`? For example, at least how many elements of `A` should be in `B` so that it satisfies your problem?

Comment: If `A` only needs to have one element equal to another element in B in the same space, then I guess this can work: `sum(A == B) > 1`

Comment: @bird 1- A and B should have the same length. 2- Elements are binary 3- A vector A is a subset of B if and only if it has the same or less number of 1s as B in the exact same place. For example A<- c(1,0,0,0) is not a subset of B<-c(0,1,1,0), but A<-c(0,1,0,0) or A<- c(0,0,1,0) or A<-c(0,1,1,0) are.

Comment: @AnilGoyal I don't think that your edit of the question to `A should have either 0 or 1 at all places wherever B has 1` is correct. I think it should have at least one matching 1.

Comment: @GKi, maybe you're right.  Let OP clarify it, please

Comment: @Carl is `A <- c(0,0,0,0)` also a subset of `B <- c(0,1,1,0)`?

Comment: @GKi Very good question. In the general definition that I have given, it technically should. However, in the context of what I am currently working on, that would be inconceivable, hence why I have not included it.

Comment: @GKi Very good question. In the general definition that I have given, it technically should. However, in the context of what I am currently working on, that would be inconceivable, hence why I have not included it.

Comment: @Carl The problem arises as the definition in the original question was: "*A is a subset of B, since A has elements 1 in the same place as B*" and in the comment "*A is a subset of B if and only if it has the same or less number of 1s as B in the exact same place*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test if `length` is `==` and if `any` values of *A* have a `1` on positions where *B* has a `1` and combine the conditions with `&&`.

```
length(A) == length(B) && any(A[B==1]==1)
#[1] TRUE
```

Fulfilling the condition in the original question: *A and B have the same length and thus have the same number of elements; yet, A is a subset of B, since A has elements 1 in the same place as B*.

To fulfill:

- `A` and `B` have the same length and thus have the same number of elements;
- `A` should have at least one `1` at places wherever `B` has `1`
- `A` can have only `0`s at all places where `B` has `0`s.

```
length(A) == length(B) && any(A[B==1]==1) && all(A[B==0]==0)
```

To fulfill:

- `A` and `B` have the same length and thus have the same number of elements;
- `A` can have only `0`s at all places where `B` has `0`s.

```
length(A) == length(B) && all(A[B==0]==0)
```

Comment: In the question I can read: *By my definition, A and B have the same length and thus have the same number of elements; yet, A is a subset of B, since A has elements 1 in the same place as B* as the condition and this is in that case true.

Comment: Oh yes I see in the comment the condition is different: *A vector A is a subset of B if and only if it has the same or less number of 1s as B in the exact same place*.

Answer (score 1):

First condition checks for same length, second checks that A doesn't have 1 on position on which B has 0.

```
if(length(A) == length(B) && all(B - A >= 0)) TRUE else FALSE
```

Comment: it's stated as `if(A subset of B)`

Comment: It does not test if *A has elements 1 in the same place as B* as asked in the original question. Try it e.g. with `A <- 0; B <- 0`.

Comment: that's not what OP asked for

Comment: **except for the final two elements**

Comment: that's your understanding, it's not stated anywhere (not saying it's wrong, my understanding is different).